# How to reveal female symbol a little more in this design?

Tags: logo, design-principles, designers, style, graphic-styles

Here, I've merged **Female symbol** and letter H. Now, **H** is clearly visible, and you can see a female symbol, but left part of symbol seems *never ending* (that is a letter **L**). Right part is fine.

**Given that all, without changing a lot, how can I reveal the icon more than present using color change or little tweaks?**

**Another Query:** The current design is little flat. What can be a better way to make this design a little stylish (for example, by using bevels or shadow/borders etc.) without destroying its beauty much?

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** This design is created to say "**Look For Her**". **For** is represented by indirect formation of **digit 4** with combination of female symbol and letter L). Let me know if you don't understand it.

[image]

Comment: I doubt bevels, shadows etc are going to look very 'modern' but my main problem is I don't know what it actually says. Is it LOIER, LFIER, LHER...?

Comment: What's the original word has to be: LHER or HER?

Comment: @Danielillo and Tetsujin my mistake. Please see the edit.

Comment: If it is supposed to say ""Look For Her", then I think the design fails. I can't see that at all.

Comment: My first thought was LOFIER. It's not clear that's supposed to be an H, especially since -IER is a very common word ending. I don't know how a casual observer would guess that the large symbol is supposed to do quadruple duty, representing the female symbol, the letter O, part of a 4, and half of an H. It's just too much.

Comment: @NuclearWang the client liked it. I can't help it much.

Comment: Is the client aware nobody's able to read this? :)

Comment: This question was more about knowing if this problem could be solved or not :(

Comment: This logo is so “clever” that it fails to communicate.

Comment: I read it as "LO+IER"

Comment: @Wildcard no personal comaparison, I understand what you said. But still would like to know: Can you please have a look a logos of Audi and Toyota (vehicles). I think a nomral person won't understand that at all. So how do they succeed?

Comment: Simple—Audi and Toyota logos aren't intended at all to communicate the *name* of the companies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ambiguity or unreadability is not always a bad thing in a logo. Being too literal can, at times, cause a design to suffer. It all inevitably comes down to how a mark is going to be used. An unreadable logo by itself can be detrimental to a startup or a company without a decent marketing budget. If the goal is to just throw the mark on items or good and have the *name of the company* recognized or legible, then I think this logo fails. And I do not know if that problem can be solved given this iteration of the artwork.

- I see no indication of the number 4 anywhere - stretching I can possibly see where you may feel the L and the symbol *sort of* make a 4.... but really.. no one else is going to pick up on that, ever
- It reads as "Lofier" or "Loher" - "Lofier" would be very unfavorable in my opinion. The "H" is a slight stretch. It wasn't the first thing I picked up on until *after* I knew the name.
- The visual dominance of the O in the symbol makes it seem *very* important - so that O is probably *always* going to be read by the viewer - Perhaps it's meant to also be an ambiguous magnifying glass as in "look, search, seek"?? It's not conveyed as that very well, if that was the intention. The O is so , so, so overpowering visually.

I'd keep working. I don't see a direction that would be similar but make the name "Look for Her" readable, either directly or indirectly.

The problem arises when I see a comment stating "The client likes it". So you've now painted yourself in a corner. The client has seen it and likes it so they expect to use it or something very close to it.

I'd be inclined to scrap this direction and start over. However.... simply playing for a few moments and trying to be more "readable" with the name and keep the same loose concept....

[image]

I'd play much more with spacing and stroke weights. The Symbol is a bit misshapen due to the thick strokes... the 4 fits wonderfully with the angles of K (but they need to be refined so they match perfectly).... these concepts need *way more polishing* ... but you get the general idea I'm sure.

Comment: Nice options...!

Comment: @Rafael this is why Scott has approximately eleventy-jillion rep. :)

Comment: Well someone felt it wasn't helpful and worthy of a down vote `:)`

Comment: Scott thanks again for your answer. But I meant to solve the given problem, and wanted to know if it's even possible to reveal the female icon little more without changing the whole design. Did I ask the question in an incorrect way? What do you say?

Comment: Hi @VikasKumar You asked fine.. and I did answer -- " I do not know if that problem can be solved given this iteration..." I think the issues with the mark are so prevalent that anything done to "slightly" alter it, isn't going to make anything better.

Comment: @VikasKumar One way to get around the client already seeing this is to start the conversation with ... *"After some testing with various professionals, some concerns were raised about X, Y, Z. So, to correct I've.... "*

Comment: @Scott thank you. Now, if you have some time, could you please look into this matter: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122677/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-design-a-standee-for-print-in-terms-of-dimension?noredirect=1#comment182843_122677 (I know it's not a right way to post here, but really wanted to know there, what makes this question a duplicate and how can I edit and explain it better)? I will be really thankful.

Comment: @VikasKumar that particular question is *so very broad* that it *can't* effectively be answered by anything short of a small novella. A couple suggestions.. 1 issue per question. If you need to ask 5 *different* questions, great... but never 5 in one question. Second.... Hardware specifics *should* be *irrelevant* when considering *design*. Yes, some hardware will be slower with more complex projects, but how to improve hardware questions (in my opinion) belong on SuperUser.com, not here.

Comment: @Scott Okay, but would it be good to ask those questions separately? If yes, I'm ready to do it. And yes, I'll surely ask the question related to hardware on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 5):

Answering your question by parts:

—  *I've merged Female symbol and letter H* —

[image: female symbol]

> The female symbol ♀ is the sign of the gender derived from the astrological symbols, which denoted the classic planet Venus. Also the feminine sign represents feminism in philosophy and sociology. This symbol is in use since the Renaissance, denoting alchemical elements, especially copper metal.

It's a symbol popularly known and accepted as it is, such that it exists as a character ♀. **Mutilating a part of this symbol can have very negative interpretations**, the arrogance of believing that we are capable of creating a new
culturally established interpretation for centuries or, much worse, cutting off part of a female entity. Remember the ablation issue still being very current and popular sensitization and is about female mutilation. Reinterpreting a sign is valid, omitting parts too, but here we are not talking about readability, but about symbols, concepts and consequences. Particularly I think anyone of the lower options are valid as a proposal, try to imagine the feminism reaction with its mutilated symbol !!!

[image]

---

Is this abstraction of the number 4 the most optimal result? I tried to find a similar font to the logo number 4 and I think none is close to the result. In addition this 4 will be part of a double reading, either with the F or H or whatever character, I think it is impossible for anyone to see it.

[image: four]

---

—  *Right part is fine* —

Of course, it's the font itself without any change! I'm agree with you, the best part of your logo ;-)

[image: font]

---

Talking about visual perception:

[image: look for her]

In the formal part of the phrase itself, at first look, the most relevant characters regarding form and perception are the double *O* and the *K*, exactly those that you have omitted in your logo :-D

In second place: *4*, *R* and *L*, I think in this order. In fact the only importance at visual level the letter *L* has is only by the reading since it's the first letter. At the formal perceptual level it could be in last place. The opposite in your logo where you give it the most important relevance by position, size and color contrasts.

Finally the *H* and *E* horizontal strokes repetition.

---

— *Without changing a lot, how can I reveal the icon more* —

Hard mission!

[image: logo]

You are asking someone to solve an impossible quiz. I think the formal shape must be restructured from the beginning and the only one can do that is you.

Personally I can help by putting in order the conceptual base of your logo:

- Name: Look for her
- Symbolic: Must have the female symbol representation ♀
- Union: Must be an assembly of characters
- The word *Look* could be replaced by a magnifying glass  as a representation of `look for`. If that's the case, study well the behaviour of the letter L, and the missing O and K. In my personal opinion they must be all or none of them. Does this lower image have any sense?

[image: ILNY]

- The burgundy is the representative color of woman

Try to see the text in different fonts, this could help:

[image: fonts]

Or much better... As I see the process and the result of your logo, I think it would be useful to forget about the vectorial result and go to the old: pencil and paper. Try to make a signature with the phrase, from there you can get a good abstraction to solve it later in vector

[image: Signature]

Comment: I like your answers because you often make a theoretical analysis. :o)

Comment: Thank you for making it clear that this design can lead to negativity :)

Answer (score 1):

Make it a crossword. Right reading order, for is for, only one letter is partially missing.

It's easy to say and scrape onto paper something. Placing the items is totally different. Here's one attempt:

[image]

Comment: However much I look at that, predominantly I'm seeing an unintended & rather unfortunate "FOOK"

Comment: Unfortunately many of us have not so glorious talent or at least habit to repeat what another person just said or wrote - not as is, but turned to be about sex and drinking with minimal changes. I have tried to get rid of that tradition. But that does not slow down someone else to say for ex. "Lock for her!" That device was common say 800 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at proposition and knowing what it should tell I noticed that the receiver is supposed to know the whole message before deciphering it. So it's assumed they will know there should be word "look" based only on one O and distorted L (notice how L is not aligned or don't have other letters width or fatness).
And based on that knowledge they should then fill the gap between "look" and "her" with four that sounds like "for".  With "her" being also shown in ambiguous way. 
Imho far too much to expect from not enough information.

So instead I would choose what is the main message in "look for her". For me it was "look" and "her". Thanks to this I can play with feminine suggestions as having "just enough" of word "her" and female symbol will lead to deciphering them in both ways.
In the word "look" I omitted the vertical line in "K" to put emphasis on the one in the next one. So to draw attention to letter H. Also by overlapping two O's in that manner I created possibility to create second female symbol in negative space between H and E.

The 4 "for" is a little pushed as I couldn't find good place for it in this approach. It would need further polish as for me it read more like 400. Maybe a subtle outline on the left side that could be tied to caring hand that envelop the message.

[image: My take]